# bootstrap loses glow form-control

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a very strange problem happening with an ASP.NET 4.5 website, using bootstrap for styling. I have set the class of the controls to `form-control-static` for alignment purposes. However, I'm getting different display results across 3 browsers.

IE9, used by some of our users, the control glows when focused or on mouseover. This is fine.

Chrome, the textbox border will go blue when focused (but no glow). Nothing happens on mouseover (fine with me).

IE11, which is the main used browser for this app, controls do not glow nor change border color on focus. However, if I click into each textbox then tab to the next, the border turns to blue **only** on tabbing to the next field. The control stays blue bordered even as I navigate through different fields (see te following screenshot).

[image]

If I use `form-control` (not static) I get nice rounded controls with blue glow on focus. But the layout is not how I want it.

```
 <div class="form-group">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblReduction" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Reduction:" Width="320px"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlReduction" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="form-control-static" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlReduction_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="220px">
                            <asp:ListItem>&lt;-- Please Select --&gt;</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDLACareComponentAward" runat="server" CssClass="form-control-static" Font-Bold="True" Text="DLA Care Component Payment Awarded (£):" Width="320px"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="DLACareComponentAwardTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control-static" MaxLength="8" Text='<%# Bind("DLACareComponentAward") %>' Width="220px" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqvalDLACareAwarded" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DLACareComponentAwardTextBox" Display="Dynamic" Enabled="False" ErrorMessage="DLA Care Component Payment Required" font-bold="true" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexDLApaymentAwarded" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DLACareComponentAwardTextBox" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="DLA Care Component Payment Awarded must be a money value" font-bold="true" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?" ValidationGroup="PIP">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDLAMobilityComponentAward" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="DLA Mobility Component Payment Awarded (£):" Width="320px"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="DLAMobilityComponentAwardTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control-static" MaxLength="8" Text='<%# Bind("DLAMobilityComponentAward") %>' Width="220px" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqvalMobilityComponent" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DLAMobilityComponentAwardTextBox" Display="Dynamic" Enabled="False" ErrorMessage="DLA Mobility Component Payment" font-bold="true" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="PIP">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexDLApaymentAwarded0" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DLAMobilityComponentAwardTextBox" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="DLA Mobility Component Payment Awarded must be a money value" font-bold="true" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?" ValidationGroup="PIP">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDailyPIPPoints" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Daily PIP Points:" Width="320px"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="DailyPIPPointsTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control-static" MaxLength="10" Text='<%# Bind("DailyPIPPoints") %>' Width="220px" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqvalDailyPIPPoints" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DailyPIPPointsTextBox" Display="Dynamic" Enabled="False" ErrorMessage="Daily PIP Points" font-bold="true" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="PIP">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexDailyPIP" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DailyPIPPointsTextBox" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Only numbers can be used for Daily PIP Points" font-bold="true" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*$" ValidationGroup="PIP">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMobilityPIPPoints" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Mobility PIP Points:" Width="320px"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="MobililtyPIPPointsTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control-static" MaxLength="10" Text='<%# Bind("MobililtyPIPPoints") %>' Width="220px" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqvalMobilityPIPPoints" runat="server" ControlToValidate="MobililtyPIPPointsTextBox" Display="Dynamic" Enabled="False" ErrorMessage="Mobility PIP Points" font-bold="true" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="PIP">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexMobilityPIPPoints" runat="server" ControlToValidate="MobililtyPIPPointsTextBox" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Only numbers can be used for Mobility PIP Points" font-bold="true" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*$" ValidationGroup="PIP">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </div>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlPIP" runat="server" Visible="false">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblPIPDailyLivingAward" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="PIP Daily Living Award (£):" Width="320px"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="PIPDailyLivingAwardTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control-static" MaxLength="8" Text='<%# Bind("PIPDailyLivingAward") %>' Width="220px" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqvalDailyLivingAward" runat="server" ControlToValidate="PIPDailyLivingAwardTextBox" Display="Dynamic" Enabled="False" ErrorMessage="PIP Daily Living Award Required" font-bold="true" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="PIP">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexDLApaymentAwarded1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="PIPDailyLivingAwardTextBox" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="PIP Daily Living Awarded must be a money value" font-bold="true" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?" ValidationGroup="PIP">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblPIPMobilityAward" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="PIP Mobility Award (£):" Width="320px"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="PIPMobilityAwardTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control-static" MaxLength="8" Text='<%# Bind("PIPMobilityAward") %>' Width="220px" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqvalmobilityAward" runat="server" ControlToValidate="PIPMobilityAwardTextBox" Display="Dynamic" Enabled="False" ErrorMessage="PIP mobility Award Required" font-bold="true" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="PIP">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexDLApaymentAwarded2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="PIPMobilityAwardTextBox" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="PIP Mobility Award must be a money value" font-bold="true" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?" ValidationGroup="PIP">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </div>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlAppealLodged" runat="server" Visible="false">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblAppealLodged" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Appeal Lodged:" Width="320px"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAppealLodged" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="form-control-static" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlAppealLodged_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="220px">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="0">&lt;-- Please Select --&gt;</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlAppealDate" runat="server" Visible="false">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblAppealLodgedDate" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Date Appeal Lodged:" Width="320px"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateLodged" runat="server" CssClass="form-control-static" Width="220px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDateLodged" WatermarkCssClass="txtwatermark" WatermarkText="dd/mm/yyyy" />
                        </div>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexDateAppealLodged" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDateLodged" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="* Enter a valid Termination Date (DD/MM/YYYY)" font-bold="true" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$" ValidationGroup="PIP">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblVSSInterest" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="VSS Interest Confirmed:" Width="320px"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlVSS" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="form-control-static" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlVSS_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="220px">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="0">&lt;-- Please Select --&gt;</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <div>
                            <br />
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlCRIType" runat="server" Visible="false">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCRIType" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="CRI Type:" Width="320px"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCRIType" runat="server" CssClass="form-control-static" Width="220px">
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">&lt;-- Please Select --&gt;</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Psychological</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Physical</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Psychological &amp; Physical</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </asp:Panel>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDLATerminationDate" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="DLA Termination Date:" Width="320px"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="DLATerminationDateTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control-static" MaxLength="10" Text='<%# Bind("DLATerminationDate") %>' Width="220px" />
                                <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="DLATerminationDateTextBox" WatermarkCssClass="txtwatermark" WatermarkText="dd/mm/yyyy" />
                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DLATerminationDateTextBox" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="* Enter a valid Termination Date (DD/MM/YYYY)" font-bold="true" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$" ValidationGroup="PIP">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqvalTerminationDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DLATerminationDateTextBox" Display="Dynamic" Enabled="False" ErrorMessage="DLA Termination Date Required" font-bold="true" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="PIP">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <div class="row text-center">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" cssclass="btn btn-success" OnClick="InsertButton_Click" OnClientClick="changeTextPIP()" Text="Insert" ValidationGroup="PIP" Width="125px" />
                                &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" cssclass="btn" onclick="InsertCancelButton_Click" Text="Cancel" ValidationGroup="PIP" Width="125px" />
                            </div>
                            <br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
```

Comment: can you share you code or working fiddle

Comment: basic formview. Code from Insert Template added